# Excel Pivot Drilldown on Sums of Flags

Tags: excel, pivot-table, drilldown

I've been hitting a wall on this today.  I'm pulling my data from a SQL DB and in my query I'm setting flags so that I can use the Pivot table to count up all the different checks I'm trying to run on the data.  A simple version of what I'm doing would look like this is below with a Greater than 90 days and Error Check flags set depended on the data in Uptime.

```
Host    Team    Uptime  >90 ErrChk
Srv1    A       15      0   0
Svr2    A       102     1   0
Srv3    B       95      1   0
Svr4    B       20      0   0
Srv5    B       21      0   0
Srv6    B       ERROR   0   1
Srv7    A       ERROR   0   1
Srv8    B       150     1   0
Srv9    A       100     1   0
Srv10   A       10      0   0
Srv11   A       125     1   0
Srv12   A       40      0   0
Srv13   B       111     1   0
Srv14   B       100     1   0
Srv15   A       15      0   0
```

If you were to plug this into Excel exactly the way that it is you will see what I'm getting at.  Once you create a Pivot table on this data and use the `Team` as the Rows and the Sum of >90 and `ErrChk` the pivot comes out and looks correct.

```
Row Labels      Sum of >90      Sum of ErrChk
A               3               1
B               4               1
Grand Total     7               2
```

But the next piece is where it gets wonky. With a Pivot table when you double click one of the values it filteres down on what makes that value, however when you do it on the value of a `SUM`, it just filteres down on the Row Label.  So for this example you would click 3 under >90 for team A to see what the 3 servers are that have been up for longer thank 90 days.  However when you do this it gives drills down to just a filter of team A showing you all of the servers, the good, the bad, the error.

My question is how can I drill down to just the items that make up that value?  I've tried all I can think of, have the filed be `NULL`, 0, calculated fields.

Comment: Not quite where I was trying to get with that, while that works its adding an extra step and for multiple flag SUMs I would have to add that many more filters to the pivot, or instruct that even though someone clicks to see the data there are extra steps involved.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an additional pivot table for the view you want. For your example you might want to add Team, then Host to Row Labels. Then add Sum of > 90 to Values. Then add > 90 to Report Filter and set the filter to 1.

These pivot tables could all be on the one worksheet pulling from the same data source as a kind of summary and the filter would be preset so there would be no need to provide instructions to those viewing the summary.

If you'd like let users change the filter easily you could add a slicer which will present all options by which the data can be filtered by.